# The point-ultraweak convergence of contractive completely positive map

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $C$ be C*-algebras. If $\phi_{n}: A \rightarrow C$ is a c.c.p (contractive completely positive) map, then the point-ultraweak cluster point of the map $\phi_{n}$ is still a c.c.p. map? Why? What about the point-norm cluster point of $\phi_{n}$?

Comment: Where are you considering the ultraweak topology? It doesn't usually make sense on a C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: @Martin Argerami In P87 of the N.P.Brown and N.Ozawa's book, the proof of the corollary 3.6.3, the author want to find a $\Phi$ which is a c.c.p. map.

Comment: In that proof, $\psi_n\circ\varphi_n$ maps into $B(H)$, where the ultraweak topology makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point-ultraweak topology is described in page 5 of Brown-Ozawa. Other authors (Arveson, Paulsen) call it the BW (for "bounded-weak") topology.

If $\phi_t:A\to B(H)$ are ccp, then by Theorem 1.3.7 in Brown-Ozawa it has a cluster point $\phi$. By replacing the net with an appropriate subnet, we can assume for notation simplicity that $\phi_t\to \phi$ point-ultraweakly.

Since the ultraweak topology agrees with the weak operator topology on bounded sets, it is enough to consider weak operator limits. So, given $X\in M_n(A)^+$ and $\xi\in H^n$,
$$
\langle \phi^{(n)}(X)\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle[\phi(X_{kj})]\xi,\xi\rangle=\sum_{k,j=1}^n\langle\phi(X_{kj})\xi_j,\xi_k\rangle=\lim_t\sum_{k,j=1}^n\langle\phi_t(X_{kj})\xi_j,\xi_k\rangle
=\lim_t\langle\phi_t^{(n)}(X)\xi,\xi\rangle\geq0.
$$
So $\phi^{(n)}$ is positive, and so $\phi$ is completely positive. A similar computation shows that $\phi$ is completely contractive.

Since norm convergence is stronger, and point-norm cluster point will also be ccp. But there is no guarantee that such a cluster point exists. It might in some cases, and it likely won't in most.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for your answer, Martin. And in some books, the ultraweak topology is called "$\sigma-$weak topology".

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. But it sounds weird when you use it as an adjective ("$\sigma$-weakly").

Comment: Hah, yes, a little.